# Mongoose getting external data from remote server

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, express

So i have an aplication made with java and that application sends data using the mongo java driver to my server but i need a way to get that data into my dashboard made with nodejs expressjs. Mongoose support getting external data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to get the mongoDB into your dashboard application created with nodejs and expressjs. I have given below two approaches choose the approach which suits you best.

> Approach 1:

1) Create and Expose REST service in your java application, which connects to MongdDB

2) Consume the REST service in your Dashboard application

Read thru these references to get more info on how to Consume a REST service in node js

https://isolasoftware.it/2012/05/28/call-rest-api-with-node-js/

https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1225/call-external-service-using-nodejs

Creating Java Restful service

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html (Using JAX-RS)

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ (Using Spring framework)

> Approach 2:

If you are using mongoose, then using Mongoose api's we can invoke the MongoDB directly(without using the Java application)

References

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-restful-crud

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd